# How can you switch from using one UIButton to another while still holding down finger?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

Imagine your keyboard. Imagine yourself placing one finger down one key, then (while holding down) moving your finger all the way across to another key on the keyboard. Now, imagine that each key on the keyboard is a `UIButton`. when you are holding your finger on the current key, this key (`UIButton`) is highlighted. Then, when the user moves across to another key, the first key is no longer highlighted, and the current key that is pressed down, is highlighted.

Now, I have a 6 x 8 grid of UIButtons each 53 x 53 pixels. So, I have 48 `UIButtons`. I want to replicate this kind of idea. The button that the users finger is upon, will have a image that is slightly lighter (to look selected like), and all others will will not be slightly lighter.

Here is my idea of how to go about this,

1) Create all 48 `UIButtons` in `viewDidLoad`. Add the lighter image to `UIControlStateHighlighted` for all `UIButtons`.

2) Add some sort of `target` for `touchUpOutside` that somehow makes the current button not highlighted and not usable. (maybe set the highlighted and `userInteractionEnabled` to no). But then how can I tell the next button to be used? And how can I say that I want the specific `UIButton` that the users fingers are under to become highlighted and in use to detect gestures and stuff.

Also, this `touchUpOutside` method may not work because all the buttons are right next to each other, and I think you have to drag far out to run this `touchUpOutside`.

It's also important to note that the buttons are not placed in equal rows and columns. Sometimes one button will actually be a `UIImage` but look like a `UIButton`. So, doing some sort of fast enumeration comparing frames for some reason will not work.

Comment: You describe some low level behavior (the fact that if you press down and drag your finger to another button), but you don't describe the broader problem you're trying to solve, so it makes answering your question a little tough. What are you trying to do? Just detecting touch down in one button and touch up in another? Or a whole series in a Swype-like typing scheme? The proposed answer might depend upon what you're trying to do.

Comment: I also don't understand your last point about not fast enumeration of frames not working (because if you're worried about different subview types, you'd just check for `isKindOfClass` to know what the right behavior was). See my answer.

Comment: I assume you meant UIImageView instead of UIImage

Comment: As for fast enumeration, you can always use `isKindOfClass` like Ryan said, but you shouldn't even need that if they are all subclasses of UIView, as they should all have the `myUIView.frame` property.  See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two observations:

1. I generally use gesture recognizers for stuff like this, not the various `touchUp...` methods.
2. I know you said you don't want a fast enumeration through the subviews, but why not? Just because some are different classes than others is not a problem (because you could just test the `isKindOfClass` method). (And, as an aside, I'm not sure why some would be buttons and some would not.) Just because they don't line up really makes no difference, either.

Anyway, for stuff like this, I frequently will put the gesture recognizer on the shared parent view (e.g. typically the view controller's view), and then enumerate through the subviews to see in which the current CGPoint is contained?

```
CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.view];

for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews)
{
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(subview.frame, location))
    {
        // do your appropriate highlighting

        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            // something for buttons
        }
        else if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
        {
            // something for imageviews
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

I don't know if any of this makes sense to you, but it seems easiest to me. If you clarify your intent, perhaps I can refine my answer further.

Just as a practical example, you could define a continuous gesture recognizer that kept track of the first and last subview that was clicked on (and if you don't start your gesture on a subview, no gesture is generated, and if you don't stop your gesture on a subview, it cancels the whole thing), e.g.:

```
@interface SubviewGestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer

@property (nonatomic,strong) UIView *firstSubview;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIView *currentSubview;

@end

@implementation SubviewGestureRecognizer

- (id) initWithTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    self = [super initWithTarget:target action:action];
    if (self)
    {
        self.firstSubview = nil;
        self.currentSubview = nil;
    }

    return self;
}

// you might want to tweak this `identifySubview` to only look 
// for buttons and imageviews, or items with nonzero tag properties, 
// or recursively navigate if it encounters container UIViews 
// or whatever suits your app

- (UIView *)identifySubview:(NSSet *)touches
{
    CGPoint location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

    for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(subview.frame, location))
        {
            return subview;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    if ([touches count] != 1)
    {
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
        return;
    }

    self.firstSubview = [self identifySubview:touches];
    self.currentSubview = self.firstSubview;

    if (self.firstSubview == nil)
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
    else
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    if (self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) return;

    self.currentSubview = [self identifySubview:touches];

    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    self.currentSubview = [self identifySubview:touches];

    if (self.currentSubview != nil)
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded;
    else
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
}

- (void)reset
{
    [super reset];

    self.firstSubview = nil;
    self.currentSubview = nil;
}
```

You could then set this up in `viewDidLoad`:

```
SubviewGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[SubviewGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouches:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

And then define your handler as such (this works with buttons and image views, taking advantage of the fact that both support `setHighlighted`):

```
- (void)handleTouches:(SubviewGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    static UIControl *previousControl = nil;

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
            previousControl = nil;

        UIView *subview = sender.currentSubview;
        if (previousControl != subview)
        {
            // reset the old one (if any)

            [previousControl setHighlighted:NO];

            // highlight the new one

            previousControl = (UIControl *)subview;
            [previousControl setHighlighted:YES];
        }
    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        if (previousControl)
        {
            [previousControl setHighlighted:NO];
            NSLog(@"successfully touchdown on %@ and touchup on %@", sender.firstSubview, sender.currentSubview);
        }
    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed)
    {
        [previousControl setHighlighted:NO];
        NSLog(@"cancelled/failed gesture");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, im a little hesitant to do it this way. Because when the User moves his finger, I want it to be instant. And, if I run this method every time i do a tiny little drag, I think problems will likely occur.

Comment: I think you'll find it's instantaneous, but obviously pursue other approaches if you want. But at the most basic level, I think all of these techniques, behind the scenes, probably use the same `UIResponder` methods, `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchedEnded`, etc., so I'm not sure if it makes much of a difference. Incidentally, I've updated my answer with a custom gesture recognizer that hides a lot of the "which subview was I over" logic, so it's a little cleaner in your touch handler routine. But certainly no offense will be taken here if you find another technique more to your liking.

Comment: @Sasquatch Unless you have thousands of buttons I wouldn't worry. Premature optimization is the root...

Comment: Please make sure you have imported UIGestureRecognizerSubclass class

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly simple way to do this.  Assuming you are creating your buttons programmatically (it would be a huge pain to do this with interface builder).  This method works in subclasses of UIViewController, UIView, and UIGestureRecognizer.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    //get the touch object
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];

    //get the location of the touch
    CGPoint *myPoint = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];

    //detect if the touch is in one of your buttons
    if ( CGRectContainsPoint(myButton.frame, myPoint){
        /*do whatever needs to be done when the button is pressed
        repeat the CGRectContainsPoint for all buttons,
        perhaps using a while or for loop to look through an array?*/
    }

}
```

This method only detects when the user puts their finger down, you will need to use these methods to detect other movements:

`touchesMoved:withEvent` detects when the finger moves across the screen without lifting up

`touchesEnded:withEvent` detects when the finger is lifted off the screen

`touchesCancelled:withEvent:` detects when something interrupts the app, like receiving a call or locking the screen